# After freezing, Ubuntu stops giving display output though cpu is still on

Tags: display, 22.04, freeze, crash

After installing Ubuntu on my old pc, I've been getting a lot of freezes. After a few seconds, the computer doesn't give display output, as well as powers off the keyboard (the mouse remains powered on though) Here are my specs

OS: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS x86_64
Kernel: 5.15.0-48-generic
DE: GNOME 42.4
CPU: Intel i3-2100 (4) @ 3.100GHz
GPU: AMD ATI Radeon X300/X550/X1050 Series
GPU: AMD ATI Radeon X600/X600
Memory: 5GB

Comment: When you downloaded the ISO you of course verified the download? https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu#1-overview How did you make the live media? What app?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I figured out the solution by an accident.

So I just changed my user (created a new one cause I ruined old one while trying some stuff) and that seems to fix the problem. Now, when the pc crashes, it gets back like 2 seconds after.

Comment: If it still crashes i would not call that fixed.